# Mouse volume control via designated scroll wheel

Tags: linux, mouse, scrolling, multimedia, xinput

I have a mouse with a designated scroll wheel which on windows controls volume by default, no driver install needed.

So far every distribution (which includes Ubuntu, Arch, Fedora) I tried doesn't support this feature on my mouse. I am currently on fedora.

I tried testing the input with xinput but it doesn't detect the scrolling of the designated scroll wheel. note that I am not referring to the scroll wheel for scrolling pages. this is a separate scroll wheel.

Comment: Check out [link1](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/smldpk/hold_down_leftclick_scroll_mouse_wheel_to_change/) and [link2](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/snpcs/using_the_mousewheel_to_control_the_volume_howto/) (if they apply).

Answer (score 0):

First, check the manufacturer's literature as to how they have implemented this **nonstandard** second scroll wheel. They likely have their own drivers -- which might, or might not, be available for Linux.

On Linux, [Input Remapper](https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper), or on Windows, [X-Mouse Button Control](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm), or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/x-mouse-button-control/) app *might* be able to read the extra wheel... or not. You'd need to experiment.

Before installing any app or driver, check it at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload).